# Typescript ReconnectingWebSocket fails to call constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I attempt to create a new [ReconnectingWebSocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reconnecting-websocket) I get the following:

`reconnecting_websocket_1.default is not a constructor`

The typescript code is:

```
import ReconnectingWebSocket, { Options } from 'reconnecting-websocket';

export class RealtimeClient {

    private reconnectingWebSocket: ReconnectingWebSocket

    constructor(private url: string, private dispatch: IDispatcher) {}

    public connect() {
        const wsOptions: Options = {
            minReconnectionDelay: 1000,
            reconnectionDelayGrowFactor: 1.0,
            connectionTimeout: 2000,
        }
        this.reconnectingWebSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(this.url, [], wsOptions)
        this.reconnectingWebSocket.onmessage = this.onMessage
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

At runtime, the resulting javascript in chrome dev tools shows that `reconnecting_websocket_1` is the ReconnectingWebSocket class as expected, however `default` is undefined, which I believe is the root cause of the failure.

```
this.reconnectingWebSocket = new reconnecting_websocket_1.default(this.url, [], wsOptions);
this.reconnectingWebSocket.onmessage = this.onMessage;
```

**NB:**

1. I am compiling to ES5 javascript (via tsconfig.json *target*).
2. I have a non-dev dependency on reconnecting-websocket
       `"reconnecting-websocket": "^4.0.0-rc5"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add compiler option `esModuleInterop` to your tsconfig.json.
You might also want to look at `socket.io-client`, which is slightly bigger, but not abandoned 3 years ago.